# Error in make install arch/x86/Makefile:245: *** You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler.. Stop

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, compiling, make

I've been trying to follow the steps given on this site
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/
to install an WiFi adapter device driver on my HP laptop.
However when i use the 
`sudo make install`
 command i get the error

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-50-generic/build M=/home/keith/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
arch/x86/Makefile:245: *** You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler..  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RI8f.png)

I also tried to use commands

```
sudo make clean
sudo make
```

Result:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-50-generic/build M=/home/keith/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
arch/x86/Makefile:245: *** You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler..  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic'
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What Do I Do to fix this error with make?